# Hide rows with double click

Tags: excel, vba

Below is an example I found to hide/open complete rows in Excel with a doubleclick.

It works for a few lines but if I want to do this for 100 lines it's a terrible job.

Is it possible to make this more code-friendly?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
If Target.Address(0, 0) = "A9" Then
    Cancel = True
    Rows("10:15").Hidden = Not Rows("10:15").Hidden
End If
If Target.Address(0, 0) = "A16" Then
    Cancel = True
    Rows("17:22").Hidden = Not Rows("17:22").Hidden
End If
If Target.Address(0, 0) = "A23" Then
    Cancel = True
    Rows("24:29").Hidden = Not Rows("24:29").Hidden
End If
If Target.Address(0, 0) = "A30" Then
    Cancel = True
    Rows("31:36").Hidden = Not Rows("31:36").Hidden
End If
If Target.Address(0, 0) = "A37" Then
    Cancel = True
    Rows("38:43").Hidden = Not Rows("38:43").Hidden
End If
If Target.Address(0, 0) = "A44" Then
    Cancel = True
    Rows("45:50").Hidden = Not Rows("45:50").Hidden
End If
```

Comment: Use the macro recorder. Select those 100 rows, hide them and the adapt the code of the recorder. Also, consider using [Outline (group) data in a worksheet](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/outline-group-data-in-a-worksheet-08ce98c4-0063-4d42-8ac7-8278c49e9aff#:~:text=el%20total%20general.-,En%20la%20pesta%C3%B1a%20Datos%2C%20en%20el%20grupo%20Esquema%2C%20haga%20clic,continuaci%C3%B3n%2C%20haga%20clic%20en%20Aceptar.) Once created you can expand/collapse all at once.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Target.Column <> 1 Then Exit Sub
    Dim r As Long
    r = Target.Row
    If (r - 2) Mod 7 = 0 And r > 2 Then
        Rows(r + 1).Resize(6).Hidden = Not (Rows(r + 1).Resize(6).Hidden)
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
If Target.Row < 9 then Exit Sub
If (Target.Row - 2) Mod 7 = 0 Then  'e.g. 9, 16, 23, 30
    hideRows Target.Row + 1
End If
End Sub


Private Sub hideRows(startRow As Long)

With Me.Rows(startRow).Resize(6)
    .Hidden = Not .Hidden
End With

End Sub
```

UPDATE after @foxfires comment:
If you like the expand/collapse idea, you can use this code:

```vb
Public Sub groupRows(ws As Worksheet)

Dim c As Range
Set c = ws.Cells(9, 1)

While LenB(c.Text) > 0
    c.Offset(1).Resize(6).EntireRow.Group
    Set c = c.Offset(7)
Wend

With ws.Outline
    .SummaryRow = xlSummaryAbove
    .ShowLevels 1
End With

End Sub
```